# How do I reference a parent from a child object with generic interfaces in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, generics, .net-4.0, interface

I have the following interface declarations:

```
interface IOrder<T> where T: IOrderItem
{
     IList<T> Items { get; set; }
}

interface IOrderItem
{
     IOrder<IOrderItem> Parent { get; set; } // What do I put here?
}
```

I want the items in the list to have a reference to the header object, so it can use the ID and other fields from the header.

In my concrete classes, it complains that I don't implement "Parent" properly.

```
class StoreOrder : IOrder<StoreOrderItem>
{
    public IList<StoreOrderItem> Items { get; set; }
}

class StoreOrderItem : IOrderItem
{       
    public StoreOrder Parent { get; set; } // This doesn't satisfy the interface
}
```

I tried setting up `IOrderItem` as `IOrderItem<T>` and passing in the Parent type, but that lead to circular reference since the Header class requries the Item class type... I got confused.

Any advice on how to implement this properly?

Comment: [This may be interesting for you](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd469487.aspx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you define your interfaces like so:

```
interface IOrder<T> where T : IOrderItem<T>
{
    IList<T> Items { get; set; }
}
interface IOrderItem<T> where T : IOrderItem<T>
{
    IOrder<T> Parent { get; set; }
}
```

You can then implement them like this to get the functionality that you expect:

```
class StoreOrder : IOrder<StoreOrderItem>
{
    public IList<StoreOrderItem> Items { get; set; }
}
class StoreOrderItem: IOrderItem<StoreOrderItem>
{
    public IOrder<StoreOrderItem> Parent { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: This corrects the compiler error, but strips the type of the `Parent` property back to `IOrder<StoreOrderItem>` instead of `StoreOrder` like it appeared the questioner was attempting. So, if you have a `StoreOrderItem` and want to do anything with the `Parent` besides operate on the `IOrder<StoreOrderItem>.Items` property you will have to cast the `Parent` to `StoreOrder` first.

Comment: @devgeezer - You are correct. However my implementation will allow any `IOrder<StoreOrderItem>` implementation to be the parent. Anything that the `IOrderItem<T>` needs to know about its parent should be implemented in the `IOrder<T>` interface, since the relationship between the two is defined at the interface level and not the implementation level.

Comment: Excellent point. I'm thinking that I read too much intent into the question. +1

Answer (score 1):

```
class StoreOrder : IOrder<StoreOrderItem>
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

class StoreOrderItem : IOrderItem
{       
    public IOrder<IOrderItem> Parent { get; set; } // This doesn't satisfy the interface
}
```

You may not specialize - `IOrder<IOrderItem>` is more general than `StoreOrder`

Comment: Why ID? Why no `IOrder<T>.IList<T>` ?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution for changing the interfaces:

```
interface IOrder<TOrder, TOrderItem> 
    where TOrderItem : IOrderItem<TOrder>
{
    IList<TOrderItem> Items { get; set; }
}

interface IOrderItem<TOrder>
{
    TOrder Parent { get; set; }
}
```

Making changes to `StoreOrder` and `StoreOrderItem` to support the interface changes *AND* adding a couple properties to each for a later test:

```
class StoreOrder: IOrder<StoreOrder, StoreOrderItem>
{
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public IList<StoreOrderItem> Items { get; set; }
}

class StoreOrderItem : IOrderItem<StoreOrder>
{
    public string ItemName { get; set; }
    public decimal ItemPrice { get; set; }
    public StoreOrder Parent { get; set; }
}
```

...and now creating `StoreOrder` and `StoreOrderItem` instances, and putting them through their paces:

```
void Main()
{
    var so = new StoreOrder { Date = DateTime.Now };
    var item = new StoreOrderItem {
            Parent = so,
            ItemName = "Hand soap",
            ItemPrice = 2.50m };
    so.Items = new [] { item };

    Console.WriteLine(item.Parent.Date);
    Console.WriteLine(so.Items.First().ItemName);
}
```

...when run, printed:

```
3/16/2012 10:43:55 AM
Hand soap
```

Another option is to scrap the above and take [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9726096/119236) and alter it by adding the Parent property with the desired type and using explicit interface implementation to avoid casting at the call-sites, making for a `StoreOrderItem` implementation something like this:

```
class StoreOrderItem : IOrderItem
{
    public string ItemName { get; set; }
    public decimal ItemPrice { get; set; }
    public StoreOrder Parent { get; set; } // note: original implementation

    IOrder<IOrderItem> IOrderItem.Parent {  // explicit interface implementation
        get { return (IOrder<IOrderItem>)this.Parent; }
        set { this.Parent = (StoreOrder)value; }
    }
}
```

My favorite of the above is the first proposal above with the two-generic parameters to `IOrder` and the unconstrained generic-parameter on `IOrderItem`. A previous version I had posted and have now edited had both interfaces each with the same two generic types each with the same constraints. I felt like this was going a bit overboard so I pared it back to the above implementation. Although there is a complete lack of constraints on `TOrder` type parameter to `IOrderItem` - attempts to fudge other types in its place (e.g., `object`) resulted in compile errors. Using `TOrder` instead of just calling it `T` provides a hint about the expected type in the absence of the type constraint. That will be my final edit - I feel it is the most succinct of my attempts; if you are curious I can provide the former implementation that had the double-generic-constrained-types on the interfaces, but this is at least my preferred this solution. cheers!

Comment: I have since learned that my first solution has a name: "Curiously Recurring Template Pattern". SO tag [ctrp]. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern

Answer (score 0):

Declaration to satisfy the interfaces:

```
class StoreOrder : IOrder<StoreOrderItem>
{
    // interface members
    public IList<StoreOrderItem> Items { get; set; }

    // own members
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

class StoreOrderItem : IOrderItem
{
    public IOrder<IOrderItem> Parent { get; set; }
}
```

To access custom members you will have to cast:

```
class StoreOrderItem : IOrderItem
{
    void Test()
    {
        int id = ((StoreOrder)this.Parent).ID;
    }
}
```